# Python Project Euler #23 Incorrect Answer

Tags: python

I have tried solving [Project Euler Problem 23](https://projecteuler.net/problem=23) in python but I am getting an answer that is below the correct one by 995. The wrong answer that I get is due to the fact that my final list does not include 12, 18, 20 and 945. However, these numbers are abundant and should not be in the final answer anyway. Therefore, the answer in Project Euler is incorrect or my logic is grossly wrong. The Project Euler Problem is,

> A number n
> is called deficient if the sum of its proper divisors is less than n
> and it is called abundant if this sum exceeds n.
>
> As 12
> is the smallest abundant number, 1+2+3+4+6 = 16,
> the smallest number that can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers is 24.
> By mathematical analysis, it can be shown that all integers greater than 28123
> can be written as the sum of two abundant numbers. However, this upper limit cannot be reduced any further by analysis even though it is known that the greatest number that cannot be expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers is less than this limit.
>
> Find the sum of all the positive integers which cannot be written as the sum of two abundant numbers.

I am fairly certain that my divisors code works well as many have the same implementation,

```py
def sum_of_divisors(n):
    sum = 1
    for i in range(2,int(n**0.5)+1):
        if n%i == 0:
            if i == n//i:
                sum += i
            else:
                sum += i + n//i
    return sum
```

My problem therefore lies in my main code, to determine if a number is abundant or not,

```py
def find_non_abd_sum(input):
    sum = 1
    #sum_set = set([1])
    abd_lst = set([])
    
    for n in range(2, input):
        if sum_of_divisors(n) > n:
            abd_lst.add(n)
        else:
            found = any((n-i) in abd_lst for i in abd_lst)
            if not found:
                sum += n
                #sum_set.add(n)
    return sum
```

Unlike many popular choices, I am only iterating through the numbers 1 to 28123, and **not** creating a list of all known sums. My thinking was that since we are asking if a number is a sum of two others, those two must be lower than it, and thus we must have already iterated them.

Specifically, if `x` is not abundant but is the sum of two abundant numbers, then there exists an `y, z` such that `y+z=x`. Therefore, both `y` and `z` **must** be less than `x`, and thus must have already been iterated before `x`.

To find if a number is not abundant, I only subtract an abundant number from `abd_lst`. If the number is abundant, then the difference of this sum should be in `abd_lst` as well. This gives the logic behind the line `any((n-i) in abd_lst for i in abd_lst)`.

My problem is that my answer is exactly 995 below, specifically, I get 4178876. The amount of abundant numbers I got is correct, 6975, and the sets match. The problem should lie in `find_non_abd_sum`, and more specifically the second part of the if statement. I am completely confused as to why this is wrong, given the fairly sound logic I set out.

Given that I am so close to the answer, I decided to implement other answers to see which numbers I am missing in `sum_set`. Here is where it gets weird. I implemented many different solutions on the forum, and those on overflow, I even got a similar one when I used Chat-GPT. These solutions all use the idea to generate a list of all possible sums using known abundant numbers. The **only** numbers that are in those sets and not mine are 12, 18, 20 and 945. However, all of these numbers are abundant and should not be in the final answer. They are respectively the first 3 abundant numbers and the first odd one. Interestingly, the sum of those numbers is 995, the exact number which I am below the supposed correct answer. Anyone got any insights as to why this is the case, and where I've gone wrong? After all, these numbers shouldn't be in the final answer anyway as they are abundant, but every other correct answer seems to have them.

I have therefore misunderstood the question or there has been an oversight as to the final answer in Project Euler, which is a stretch given its been solved almost 200K times.

P.S: Before voting to close, this *exact* problem has not been asked. One, every 'correct solution' on overflow, no matter the language, I've seen contains 12,18, 20 and 945. Two, I am not asking how to solve this problem faster. On the input 20161 this code takes me about 0.31 seconds to run, the fastest I've seen on stack and Proj Euler forums.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Project Euler #23 - Python Non Abundant Sums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45638830/project-euler-23-python-non-abundant-sums)

Comment: first you shadow the input variable `n` which is incredibly confusing.   second why are you doing anythign other than just adding `n` to the `sum` when its not abundant? what the heck is significance of found?

Comment: @UpAndAdam Thanks for spotting that! I changed `n` and `sum` on browser and didn't realise how bad it ended up, should be better now. The linked question is quite different and I don't have the same problem. As noted, I actually used the answers from that post, and they had the same issues.  My (non) and abundant lists are the exact same except from the numbers noted, which are not in my non-abundant list (and should not be) but are in others, which have the correct answer. As for `found`, I just bloated it up to highlight thats where the logic error should be :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this answer is the most efficient or the best possible solution, but several years ago, I solved the problem based on the following logic.

Based on the problem description, we know that all integers that cannot be written as the sum of two abundant numbers must lie between 1 and 28123.  This must be true since numbers smaller than 12 are non-abundant numbers and based on the data numbers larger than 28123 are all formed by the summation of abundant numbers. According to Wolfram Mathworld’s discussion on Abundant Numbers, “Every number greater than 20161 can be expressed as a sum of two abundant numbers. ” So our upper bound is 20161 instead of 28123.

In addition, Wolfram's Mathworld discussion states “Every number greater than 20161 can be expressed as a sum of two abundant numbers. ”  In addition, it also notes that there are only 21 abundant numbers less than 100, and they are all even. The first odd abundant number is 945.  The other observation made is that in determining if a number is amiable, I don’t need to go from 1 to nmb-1, since I know 1 is always a product and the largest product can only be nmb/2

Accordingly, I set the upper bound at 20161 instead of 28123 and determine the solution by the following pseudo code:

```
Let MV <- 20161
amb_nm = {}
nm_sum = 1
For n in range (1, MV-1):
    If is_amb_nm(n):
        amb_nm.add(n)
    else:
         if not any (n –amb in amb_nm for amb in amb_nm):
              nm_sum += n
return nm_sum

Determine if a number is amiable by:
Def is_amb_nm(nmb):
    pset = {1}
    for n in range(nmb//2+1, 1, -1):
        if nmb%n == 0:
             pset.add(n)
return nmb < sum(pset)
```

The above pseudo code was converted to Python as follows:

```
def sum_proper_divisors(nmb):
    """
      Compute the sum of the proper divisors of nmb
    """
    p_set= set()
    if nmb <= 2:
        if nmb == 2:
            p_set.add(1)
    else:
        p_set.add(1)
        for pn in range(nmb//2 + 1, 1, -1):
            if nmb%pn == 0:
                p_set.add(pn)
    return sum(p_set)

def is_amb_nm(nmb):
    """
     return true if nmb is an amiable number
     that is return true if the sum of proper divisors < nmb
    """
    return nmb < sum_proper_divisors(nmb)

def main():
    """
      Compute solution to euler problem 23
    """
    max_val = 20162
    t0 = process_time()
    amb_nm = set()
    nm_sum = 0
    for n in range (1, max_val):
        if is_amb_nm(n):
            amb_nm.add(n)
        if not any((n-amb in amb_nm) for amb in amb_nm):
            nm_sum += n
    t1 = process_time()
    print("Problem 23 The Sum Non-abundant Sums:", nm_sum)
    print("Total Time to solve problem:", t1-t0, "secs")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Which produces the following output:
Problem 23 The Sum Non-abundant Sums: 4179871
Total Time to solve problem: 6.671875 secs

Comment: I ran your code and it seems that 12, 18, 20 and 945 are all in your `nm_sum` despite all of them being non abundant numbers. Whilst I initially done a similar solution to yours, the code I done above was to optimise it so it can be computed in less than 0.5 seconds.  This leads me to believe that the final solution in project Euler could in fact be wrong, as those numbers sum to 995, which is what I am below the supposed correct answer. As I said, I've tried many different supposed solution s but they all somehow contain 12, 18, 20 and 945.

Comment: Although your code looks almost the exact same as mine, when `n=12` both `if` statements are run in the loop. On the second `if` statement, we get `(n-amb)` but the only value for `amb` is also 12 giving 12-12=0 and thus you'll add 12 to `nm_sum` as 0 is not in `amb_set`. This is the same reason as to why 18, 20 and 945 are added to the `nm_sum`, which they shouldn't be as they're abundant. Adding 0 to the base set will give you the same answer as mine, or changing it to an if-else. I solved most of PE 6/7 yrs ago, looking at it with more knowledge it seems that #23's answer is wrong.